# Android fragment defined in XML is different instance inside fragment than in its parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have an activity defined with a fragment described in XML. In the activity, I retrieve a reference to the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragment = (DetailActivityFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    ...
}
```

I call the fragment's (custom) updateUI() method, and it has a different ID than that in the activity:

```
DetailActivity: tbm 440; got fragment: (0x038c6009) (invisible)
DetailActivityFragment: tbm 162; fragment: (0x05f54af9) updating UI
```

Then, when the fragment is destroyed:

```
DetailActivityFragment: tbm 131; destroying fragment (0x038c6009)
```

i.e. the same fragment that was created inside the activity, and *different* from the actual fragment.

In case it matters, here's how I log the fragment IDs:

```
Log.d(TAG, String.format("tbm 162; (0x%08x) updating UI", System.identityHashCode(this));
```

Also, the ID shown in the 'tbm 162' log statement is always the same, and always matches the ID of the first time the fragment was instantiated.

Is there any particular reason for this perversity? How can a fragment's im-memory ID change between the time it is instantiated and the time the fragment is referenced inside itself? The issue of course is that inside the updateUI method, UI elements are referenced that are contained within the (now hidden and detached) original fragment, so the UI never actually changes visibly.

TIA!

Edit:

The updateUI() method does nothing but display some fields, so I don't think it is relevant, but as requested in case I'm missing something:

```
public void updateUi(final InformativeBean bean) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("tbm 162; (0x%08x) (%s) updating UI",
                             System.identityHashCode(this),
                             this));

    if (mView == null || bean == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (bean.getBattery() != null) {
        TextView battery_info = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.battery_field);
        battery_info.setText(String.format("%s%%", bean.getBattery().getPercentage()));
    }

    ImageView burnin_view = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.burnin_flag_image);
    if (bean.isBurninComplete()) {
        burnin_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flag_burnin_complete);

    } else {
        burnin_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flag_burnin_incomplete);

    }

    Program program = bean.getProgram();
    Program new_program = bean.getPendingProgram();

    TextView current_program_view = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.current_program_field);
    current_program_view.setBackgroundColor(mTransparentColor);

    if (new_program == null) {
        if (program == null) {
            return;
        }

        current_program_view.setText(program.toString());

    } else if (program == null || program.equals(new_program)) {
        current_program_view.setText(new_program.toString());

    } else {
        current_program_view.setText(String.format("%s -> %s", program, new_program));
        current_program_view.setBackgroundColor(mProgramBackgroundColor);

    }

}
```

Edit:

Even weirder, the fragment changes ID even within itself:

```
DetailActivityFragment: tbm 065; (0x06a9e492) (DetailActivityFragment{6a9e492 #0 id=0x7f0d0075}) in attach
DetailActivityFragment: tbm 104; (0x06a9e492) (DetailActivityFragment{6a9e492 #0 id=0x7f0d0075}) in onCreateView
DetailActivity: tbm 463; got fragment: (0x06a9e492) (DetailActivityFragment{6a9e492 #0 id=0x7f0d0075}) (invisible)
DetailActivityFragment: tbm 162; (0x068d3e1a) (DetailActivityFragment{68d3e1a}) updating UI
```

so it's 0x06a9e492 in onAttach and onCreateView (and that's the reference the activity receives), but stubbornly 0x068d3e1a inside updateUI.

Comment: can you post your custom updateUI method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation it turns out that a field inside the activity containing the errant fragment was holding a reference to that activity. Changing the field so it is passed the *current* activity instance (vs holding an implicit reference to the field's outer activity) fixed the issue. I'm still somewhat confused as to how a fragment's ID can change even while it is 'active', but at least I can make progress.

This helped a lot: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html. I didn't spot the problem at first as being a kind of leak.

Effectively, this was the (original, errant) code:

```
DetailActivity
    ...
    some_field = new Listener() {
        // The outer activity is retained, causing its fragment to be (partially?) re-used.
        onSomeEvent() {
            Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Got Some Event", ...).show();
        }
    };
    ...
```

And the new, working code is more like:

```
DetailActivity
    ...
    some_field = ListenerWithActivity.getInstance(this);
    ...

ListenerWithActivity:

     public static ListenerWithActivity getInstance(Activity activity) {
         ListenerWithActivity existing = getExisting();
         if (existing == null) {
             existing = new ListenerWithActivity();
         }

         existing.setActivity(activity);
         return existing;
     }

     public void onSomeEvent() {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Got Some Event", ...).show();
     }
```